# Web Api Swagger Parameter Example

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

Using ASP.NET 5 Web API with MVC Versioned API Explorer, is there a way to auto generate the example for a parameter like described in the Swagger docs: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/

I'm currently using XML Comments, but I don't see a way to provide the example for a parameter. The <remarks> XML Comment doesn't apply to parameters and only to the operation.

What I'd like to do is have the example auto-generated for the following model

```
public record GetSpecsCommand {
  /// <summary>filter results by already selected specs</summary>
  /// <remarks>
  ///     {
  ///       "selectedspecs.year": "2020"
  ///     }
  /// </remarks>
  public IDictionary<string, string> SelectedSpecs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After I posted this, I searched through the github code and found that it supports the <example> XML comment. After changing <remarks> to <example> my example was magically added to the generated swagger doc.